# Power Bi Power Query Header Update Automatically when Excel Table Header Name Change

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Is there a way to let Power BI Power Query auto update column header when Excel table header updated?

What I practicing now is manually change in formula. My concern is, somebody may amend the Excel table without my knowledge and I will have hard time to troubleshoot.

Comment: Are people adding columns or just changing the column titles in source data? Adding columns is not usually an issue. Renaming source data columns can be addressed by NOT promoting the first row as the header, and just removing that row as an early step, then using the data as Column1, Column2, etc, or manually renaming and assigning names.

Comment: If it is just the column header that is being changed (and the data type, order,  and all transformations will be the same), then you can refer to the "current" column names with `Table.ColumnNames(previous step)` and then index into that array to use the new names. You'd need to do this at each step where you have a column name hard coded.